# Show and hide sub menu using React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to redo my menu with React Hooks and here's my latest attempt.

The only issue I have is that when I click `sub-menu-click`, all the sub menu opens.

How can I make it so that only the child is open when the parent (i.e. Item 1) is clicked?

Thank you.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export default () => {
    const [menuOpen, setMenuOpen] = useState(false);
    const [subMenuOpen, setSubMenuOpen] = useState(false);
    const toggleClassName = menuOpen ? 'is-open' : '';

    const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
        query {
            site {
                siteMetadata {
                    title
                }
            }
        }
    `);
    return (
        <Layout>
            <Menu>
                <div class="menu-left">
                    <Link to="/">{data.site.siteMetadata.title}</Link>
                </div>
                <Hamburger
                    className={toggleClassName}
                    onClick={() => setMenuOpen(!menuOpen)}
                >
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                </Hamburger>
                <div class="menu-right">
                    <ul className={toggleClassName}>
                        <li class="menu-item has-children">
                            <Link to="/">
                                Item 1
                            </Link>
                            <div
                                class={`sub-menu-click`}
                                onClick={() => setSubMenuOpen(!subMenuOpen)}
                            >
                                <span></span>
                            </div>
                            <ul
                                class={`sub-menu && ${
                                    subMenuOpen ? 'is-open' : ''
                                }`}
                            >
                                <li class="menu-item">Sub-Item 1</li>
                                <li class="menu-item">Sub-Item 2</li>
                                <li class="menu-item">Sub-Item 3</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="menu-item has-children">
                            <Link to="/">
                                Item 2
                            </Link>
                            <div
                                class={`sub-menu-click`}
                                onClick={() => setSubMenuOpen(!subMenuOpen)}
                            >
                                <span
                                    class={`${subMenuOpen ? 'is-open' : ''}`}
                                ></span>
                            </div>
                            <ul
                                class={`sub-menu && ${
                                    subMenuOpen ? 'is-open' : ''
                                }`}
                            >
                                <li class="menu-item">Sub-Item 1</li>
                                <li class="menu-item">Sub-Item 2</li>
                                <li class="menu-item">Sub-Item 3</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </Menu>
        </Layout>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution to this to move the `SubMenu` to a different component and let it have it's own state.

```
const SubMenu = () => {
  const [subMenuOpen, setSubMenuOpen] = useState(false);
  return (
    <li class="menu-item has-children">
     <Link to="/">
          Item 1
     </Link>
     <div
        class={`sub-menu-click`}
        onClick={() => setSubMenuOpen(!subMenuOpen)}
      >
          <span></span>
      </div>
      <ul
          class={`sub-menu && ${
              subMenuOpen ? 'is-open' : ''
          }`}
      >
          <li class="menu-item">Sub-Item 1</li>
          <li class="menu-item">Sub-Item 2</li>
          <li class="menu-item">Sub-Item 3</li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  )
}
```

and render this component in place for SubMenu in Menu component.

In case you need to control the opening of SubMenu from the Menu component, you have an array of subMenuIds currently open or a single ID according to your use case.

Comment: Yes, actually this is what I did
```
    const [subMenuOpen, setSubMenuOpen] = useState(false);
    const [subMenuOpen2, setSubMenuOpen2] = useState(false);``` Just not sure if it is the right way.

Comment: That's just creating a submenu state for each one you have, which becomes a pain when you add/remove submenus according to requirement. What is wrong with having a seperate component for it?

Comment: No, there is nothing wrong with it. I was just stating what I did before I posted here. I'm gonna try your suggestion. Thank you.